# android sqlite cursor crashes the app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

Hello Stackoverflow members!

There is a strange problem in my app. When there is a few db rows (more than 0) in the table, the query works good. when there is no rows in the table, the app crashes ,and then,  if I remove these lines, the app works ok:

```
        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("Select * from users ORDER BY `ID` DESC" ,null);
    result.moveToFirst();
   String lastuser = result.getString(resultSet2.getColumnIndex("username"));
```

I hope you can help me =]

Comment: **ALWAYS** include the logcat in your question if you get exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the crash is caused by the result not having any rows. You can check how many rows you obtained by using the `getCount` method on your cursor. If it's zero, do not try to get results from an empty set.

You can read more about cursors [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).

Answer (score 0):

After making your query, the cursor will be before the *first* position. So you have to move it to the *first* position, as you already do it with `result.moveToFirst()`. However, if your result was empty, the there is no *first* position and you get an `Exception`.

What you could do is either test

```
if(result.moveToFirst()){
       // here you can access the content
}
```

or you try it with a loop (that way you can also react on results with multiple rows)

```
while(result.moveToNext()){
      String lastuser = result.getString(resultSet2.getColumnIndex("username"));
      // here you can access ALL row entries one after another, or just the one row
}
```

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) is a clear tutorial on using SQLite – hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First change your query as(remove single quote from **ID** )

```
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("Select * from users ORDER BY ID DESC" ,null);
```

And as @Gooey suggest You can check how many rows you obtained by using the `getCount`.

So use

```
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("Select * from users ORDER BY ID DESC" ,null);

if ((result != null) && (result.getCount() > 0)) {
    result.moveToFirst();
    String lastuser = result.getString(resultSet2.getColumnIndex("username"));
}
```

And post logcat exception,if still problem occur.